# Fixing syntax of number of line reading function

Tags: c++, function, ifstream

I tried making a program earlier that tells the user then number of char, words, and lines in a text file. I made functions to determine the numbers of each, yet I was passing them by value. This resulted in an error since after reading the number of char it would be at the end of the file and then output zero for the other two. Now I cant seem to rewrite my functions so that the file is open and closed each time its checked for char, words, and lines. Any one see where my errors are?? Thanks! (just copied and pasted one of my functions for now).

```
int num_of_lines(ifstream file)
{
    string myfile;
    myfile = argv[1];

    ifstream l;
    l.open(myfile);

    int cnt3 = 0;
    string str;

    while(getline(file, str))cnt3++;
    l.close();

    return(cnt3);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ 
    int num_of_char(ifstream file);

    string file;
    file = argv[1];

    if(argc == 1)die("usage: mywc your_file"); 

    ifstream ifs;

    ifs.open(file);

    if(ifs.is_open())
    {
        int a, b, c;

        a = num_of_lines(ifs);

        cout <<"Lines: " << a << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cerr <<"Could not open: " << file << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    ifs.close();

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't write three functions to do this. Write one function that reads a character at a time, count each you read, and classify the characters to determine if it's "in a word" - on each transition from "in word" to "not in word" count up number of words, and if it's a newline, count up number of lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to "reopen" a file other than knowing the name and creating a new `ifstream`, but you can use the `seekg` member function to set your read position in the file, and setting it to 0 will have the next read operation start from the beginning of the file.

A stream is not possible to copy, so you can't pass it "by value", but must pass it by reference.

```
int num_of_lines(ifstream &file)
{
    int count = 0;
    string str;

    while (getline(file, str)) {
        count++;
    }
    file.seekg(0);

    return count;
}
```

For the full problem, I agree with Mats Petersson, though.  Counting both characters, lines and words in one pass will be much more efficient than reading through the file three times.

Comment: @Zach: From Rasmus's example, with the line read, number of characters in that line can be obtained from line length. Tokenize the line with space separator you will have number of words in a line. It will be that simple. Accumulated this per line character and word count will give you total characters and word count in the file.